# Can we use Share point for multiple user view and input of excel users. If so then how

Tags: excel, sharepoint

I want to know if it is possible for multiple users of one excel file , to update data and view this file. If so then how?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to Microsoft about this exact situation, and it turns out that the only way in Excel to have multiple users **editing** an Excel file at the same time is by using Excel Online. Unfortunately, that means that macros, VBA, active-x controls, and the like are not an option. If the file is checked out or you want to use the full-functionality of Excel from your computer you are out of luck.